# Parse a string in php

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can parse this string to get a certain name or string. What I need to parse is:

```
items/category/test.txt
```

To get it with out `test.txt` of course there will be different names so I can't just replace it.

I need the result to be:

```
items/category/
```

Also how can I parse it to get `/category/` only?

Comment: What things have you already tried and why didn't they work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's `pathinfo()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$info = pathinfo('items/category/test.txt');
$dirPath = $info['dirname'];

// OR

$dirPath = pathinfo('items/category/test.txt', PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

// Output: items/category
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode to get the above string as array

```
$string = "tems/category/test.txt";
$string_array = explode("/",$string);
print_r($string_array); // Will Output above as an array
// to get items/category/
$var = $string_array[0].'/'.$string_array[1];
echo $var; //will output as items/category/ 
$var2 = '/'.$string_array[1].'/';
echo $var2; //will output as /category/
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best chance is `explode("/","items/category/test.txt")` .
This will splice the string every time it finds **/** returning an array, whereas `implode` (`join` is an alias of it) will join an array of strings, so

```
$spli=explode("/","items/category/test.txt");
implode($spli[0],$spli[1]);
```

Should do the trick for the first case, returning `items/category`
For `category` alone, `$spli[1]` is enough.

Of course, you may pass the string as a variable, for instance
`$foo="items/category/test.txt;"
explode("/",$foo);`
etc.